# Is it possible to get a python program that uses tkinter to run in a web page using flask?

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

I have a python program that I would like to use in a web server. For that I need to convert it to web environment. I read that you can do it with flask. the challenge is that the program is a GUI made with tkinter. If I run the following program through the cmd: flask run, it runs in the local host,            (http://127.0.0.1:5000/). If I copy the address and put it in a web browser, I get the error Internal Server Error in the web window, but a new window open in my computer with the checkbutton and the label. The program works; What I need is to put that window with the checkbutton and the label inside the web window, so I can eventually put it on a server. (I have hundreds of widgets for what i was forced to use the place.method and I don't want to code everything from scratch in another language). Is there anyway to do it?

```
from flask import Flask
from tkinter import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    root = Tk()

    out = Label(root, text="0", bg="red")

    def out_result():
        out.configure(text="button pressed")

    button1 = Checkbutton(root, command=out_result)

    button1.place(x=20, y=20)
    out.place(x=50, y=20)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is simply not what Tkinter does.  To present a GUI on the web, you need to express it as HTML (and possibly some JavaScript).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  "Is there any way to do it?" is a system design issue, too broad for this site.  You need to research methods for deploying an app to the web.

Comment: I don't think my question was broad as I only wanted to know if is possible to convert a python program with tkinter GUI into web window using flask. Apparently and as @jasonharper confirm, the answer is a simple "no". I don't understand how the question is broad then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot run tkinter programs via a flask app. Tkinter applications require a physical display, or an emulated physical display. It's not literaly impossible -- I know there is at least one website that lets you run tkinter code in a browser -- but I'm sure it would be much easier to rewrite your code than to try to run it in a browser.

TL;DR: while not literally impossible, it will not work out of the box.